# Move required files where they need to go

Tags: python, file, directory, move

I'm working on a Python script that unzips a compressed directory and installs some files. When you unzip the compressed file, there could be files like `./usr/bin/package` or `./var/lib/package`. The unzipped directory contains the names of the dirs where they actually need to go. Lets say the directory structure looks like:

```
./zippedfile.zip
./usr
    /bin
        /package
./var
    ./lib
        ./package
```

Now I need to move the required files where they need to go. For example I need to move `./usr/bin/package` to the actual `/usr/bin/` directory. Thing is, it's not predictable which folders there may be, so the script needs to find the required directories and move them. Thanks, hopefully I made the question clear.

Comment: will everything be relative to / then?

Comment: Yes. If I have the file `./usr/bin/package` I want to move it to `/usr/bin/package`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the zipfile module to read the zip file and `extract(name, dest)` to extract each file.  For example:

```
import sys
import zipfile

def unzip(path, root='/'):
    zh = zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r')
    for name in zh.namelist():
        zh.extract(name, root)
    zh.close()

unzip(sys.argv[1])
```

If a file within the zip has a path of `./usr/bin/script` it will be extracted to `/usr/bin/script`.

Usage:

```
% python unzip.py myfiles.zip
```

**Update**: To handle tars, use the [tarfile module](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html). This detects the compression type using the file extension (gzip, bzip2):

```
import os
import sys
import tarfile

def untar(path, root='/'):
    mode = 'r'
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    if ext in ('.gz', '.bz2'):
        mode += ':' + ext[1:]
    th = tarfile.open(path, mode)
    for info in th.getmembers():
        th.extract(info, root)
    th.close()

untar(sys.argv[1])
```

**Updated** If you can't use the zipfile or tarfile modules, you can invoke corresponding system commands to get the same results:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def untar(path, root):
    subprocess.call(['tar', '-C', root, '-xf', path])

def unzip(path, root):
    subprocess.call(['unzip', os.path.abspath(path)], cwd=root)

path = sys.argv[1]
dest = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest)
if path.endswith('.zip'):
    unzip(path, dest)
else:
    untar(path, dest)
```

Comment: Ah alright. Is there any way to do this with lets say a tarred file, not just a zip file?

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do it without any extra module like tarfile or zipfile?

Comment: Cool, glad its helpful.  I've updated the answer with an example of invoking system commands to extract the archives.

Comment: Ah interesting. And it will move them to where they need to be without overwriting crucial system files?

Comment: You'd need to use the tarfile/zipfile solution, and as you read each file use os.path.exists() to determine if the path already exists before extracting and overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, pretty much of what you need is in the `os.path` module in the standard library. Some useful functions there:

- [os.path.exists](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists): Return True if path refers to an existing path. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.
- [os.path.isdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir): Return True if path is an existing directory. This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isdir() can be true for the same path.

If you need to invoke shell commands to actually move the directories, you can use the `subprocess` module ([see documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)) also in the standard library.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile, os
zipped = zipfile.ZipFile('zippedfile.zip')
os.chdir('/')
zipped.extractall()
```